# vue-image-upload-resize reset image file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue-image-upload-resize in my Vue project.

All works fine except I have two issues

1. How can I remove the text near the 'choose file' button?

[image]

2. How can I reset the control after file upload? Basically when I try and upload the same file again, it does not call the setImage event. I do not want to use JQuery here

Answer (score 1):

1. 

HTML:

```
<div class="input">
    <image-uploader></image-uploader>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

2. You can use [$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)

HTML:

```
<div class="input" @click="initiate">
    <image-uploader ref="image"></image-uploader>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
methods: {
    initiate() { this.$refs.image.$el.children[1].value = "" }
}
```